# Snake game boundary checking

Tags: c++, bounds

I am writing a simple console snake game,when the 'O' snake hits the wall '#' it's game over but for some reason it ends one before the wall from left to right,top and bottom works fine.

I tried debugging by printing y(I know should be the other way around not good design by me) and y displays it's position as 0 just before the wall so does that mean the wall is -1? but it can't possibly be -1 because I set i = 0 not -1,

so flustered as to whats going wrong also note my code is quite messy but I am pretty new and still learning good style

```
    void draw(){

       system("cls");

         bool notFirst = false;
         bool notLast = false;

         for(int i = 0; i <= HEIGHT+2; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j <= WIDTH+2; j++){

                if(i > 0){
                    notFirst = false;
                }

                if(i < HEIGHT+2){

                    notLast = false;
                }

                if(i == 0 && j <= WIDTH-1){

                    cout << "#"; // top wall
                    notFirst = true;
                }

                if(i == HEIGHT+2 && j <= WIDTH-2){

                    cout << "#"; // bottom wall
                    notLast = true;
                }

                if(j == 0 && i != 0){

                    cout << "#"; // #
                }
                if(j == WIDTH-1){

                    cout << "#";
                }
                if(x == i && y == j){

                        if(x == 0 || x == HEIGHT+2){

                            gameOver = true;
                        }
                        if(y == 0){

                            gameOver = true;
                        }
                        cout << y; // DEBUG
                        cout << "O";
                }
                else if(fruitX == i && fruitY == j){
                    cout << "F";
                }
                else{
                    if(!notFirst && !notLast){
                    cout << " ";
                    }
                }
            }
               cout << endl;
         }



       }


int main()
{
   setUp();
   while(!gameOver){

   draw();
   input();
   logic();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why the C language tag?  The C language doesn't have `cout` nor `bool`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews C99 has `bool`, defined in `stdbool.h` which is a macro of `_Bool`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews C actually does have `bool` these days.  It is defined to be `_Bool` which was added in C99.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons:  Sorry, but _Bool is implemented as an integer and not treated as a true Boolean type.  Look it up in `stdbool.h`.  I've had to implement many workarounds to resolve MISRA C 2004 compliance.  Also, I stated `bool` as the type, not `_Bool`.

Comment: Regardless of `bool`'s status in C,  I really doubt the asker is left-shifting `cout` `endl` bits and discarding the result, so I've nuked the C tag.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The macro `bool` expands to `_Bool` in `stdbool.h`.  This was done for backwards compatibility's sake with many projects defining their own `bool` type.  The point being that `bool` is a perfectly normal keyword to be used in C code.  Furthermore, `_Bool` is not merely implemented as an integer.  A scalar value assigned to a `_Bool` type will be represented as either `0` if it is zero, or `1` if it is non-zero.

Comment: In `for(int i = 0; i <= HEIGHT+2; i++){` the `<=` is probably giving you an off-by one.

Comment: Most development environments, and all that would be worth using to learn C++, provide some debugging software that will allow you control the execution of the program. This will let you step through the program line by line and inspect the variables as you go. Often this is easier and a more-complete view of the program than inserting debug statements.

Comment: "...note my code is quite messy but I am pretty new and still learning good style." Better style will go a long, long way toward keeping you out of messes like this. Often it is better to start over than to try to find "the bug" in spaghetti code. One thing to avoid is "bread crumbs" like `notFirst` and `notLast`, sprinkled along the path to show where you've been. The crumbs can go stale or be eaten.  They can be difficult to reason about. Those mystery +2's  and -2's look suspect also. What has "2" got to do with the problem?

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. There is no `main()` in the code.

Comment: @ user4581301 how would <= be giving me off by one? I tried just using < and still the same problem

and true Jive I just added them because they made the board look tidier